# iPhone 4S video showing as 568 x 320 pixels resolution

Tags: video, iphone, resolution

I was under the impression that the iPhone 4S recorded video at 1080p by default (using the native camera app). But when I send a video to myself via email and look at the video properties it is 568 x 320 pixels resolution. I wonder if this has to do with some compression given that it is being "shared" by email.

In that case, how do I extract the video without losing its pixel resolution?

Using iOS 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue relates to the fact that the video is being sent by email and the iPhone will compress the video for this purpose. It is not related to an email server capacity for attachments.

Reference here:
http://www.ilounge.com/index.php/articles/comments/transferring-videos-from-iphone-4s-to-computer

In order for video to be transferred at full resolution, the iPhone needs to be connected to a computer via USB. This will allow transfer of the entire file, for example using iPhoto.

When transferring a video file by email, a progress bar indicating compression is seen at the moment of transmittal, which measn the file is being compressed in resolution although it remains at full resolution within the phone until it is deleted.

In addition it is recommended to unlock the phone (if using a passcode) before connecting, to have access to this read/write functionality.